# Scroll with iframe in phonegap iOS

Tags: html, ios, cordova, iframe, scroll

If have an iframe in my PhoneGap app. The frame has been given a height of 1000. 
By adjusting its width to 50% I can scroll by touching the parent on the space next to the frame. But when I try to scroll by touching the frame itself, there is no response.

I looked for this problem and some issues have been reported that came with a solution including the -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; but no luck.

```
#content_wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    z-index:300;
}


#content_wrap  .content_container {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#FFF;
}

#tickets {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    margin:0px;
    height:auto;
}

#ticketFrame {
    height:1000px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

The html:

```
<div id="content_wrap">
   <div class="content_container">
      <div id="tickets">
         <iframe src="someurl" frameborder="0" id="ticketFrame"></iframe>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am a fan of using display inline block and float left as u can see ;)

What to do to be able to scroll with touchscreen in phonegap?

Comment: Is the height of the content in the iframe greater than 1000px? If not, there will be nothing to scroll. Have you tried setting the height of the iframe to 100%?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon thx, just tried that but nope, not working.. Still not scrolling. Though if it is a 1000px, it is beyond the height of the screen of the phone and so it should still be scrolling. Maybe not the frame itself, but sure the parent should right? and like i said, i can scroll when i touch the parent on the side (avoiding the frame)

Comment: have you tired 1000px with `scrolling="no"` on the iframe. sometimes you have to disable the scroll of one element to gain scrolling on the parent element

Comment: @DawsonLoudon yes i have ;) but still not working ;(

Comment: how about use media query to show two buttons (up/down) similar to this http://codepen.io/antonlydike/pen/ALWLpq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe problem is your iframe tag? `</iframe">`

if its not, add/change your css and try again.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#content_wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    z-index:300;
}

#content_wrap  .content_container {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#FFF;
}

#tickets {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    margin:0px;
    height:100%;
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#ticketFrame {
    height:1000px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but this was just an error I made here on stack and thus this is not the source of my problem. (unfortunately).

Comment: your code is not working on ios safari. i think its not phonegap problem.  I edit css again. now scrolling working on ios safari. can you try on phonegap?

Comment: @MartHaarman my Code is working on safari http://www.mangal.ist/aaa.html are you sure?

Comment: Yes there it is, but not in the css code you provided for the app

Comment: So i have set the width to 50%, therefore i have a white space on the right side of my iframe. The odd is that when i scroll over this white area, the whole thing does scroll vertically. However, when i scroll over the iframe itself with my fingers it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142200/discussion-between-mart-haarman-and-apsuva).